# parsing a specific JSON data

Tags: php, android, json

i am making a android application n use a .php file to call java script file that returns me a JSON output, now my problem is the output is in a valid JSON format, but i am confused as to how to parse the values. the output is

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
  "Kambarganvi road, Durgadakeri, Karnataka 580011, India",
  "St Inez Road, Santa Inez, Panjim, Goa 403001, India",
  "Dr Braganza Pereira Road, Santa Inez, Panjim, Goa 403001, India",
  "Dayanand Bandodkar Marg, Santa Inez, Panjim, Goa 403001, India",
  "St Inez Road, Santa Inez, Panjim, Goa 403001, India",
  "18th June Road, Santa Inez, Panjim, Goa 403001, India"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Suyog Residency, St Joaquim Road, Borda, Margao, Goa 403602, India" ],
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "133 km",
              "value" : 132717
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "1 day 4 hours",
              "value" : 100199
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "33.4 km",
              "value" : 33427
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "6 hours 54 mins",
              "value" : 24832
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "33.5 km",
              "value" : 33518
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "6 hours 55 mins",
              "value" : 24923
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "33.8 km",
              "value" : 33834
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "7 hours 0 mins",
              "value" : 25170
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "33.5 km",
              "value" : 33503
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "6 hours 55 mins",
              "value" : 24893
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "33.5 km",
              "value" : 33457
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "6 hours 55 mins",
              "value" : 24880
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

i want to parse the values in such a way that i can place the distances of the result should be put in a data structure like an array and then sort them.

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: Use `json_decode`: http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: Follow that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259638/responsewrong-user-registration-via-android-app-using-http-post-not-working/23259970#23259970

Answer (score 0):

use this to make own model .

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

after making model you can use bwlow code.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(jData, AddPostModel.class);
```

AddPostModel have all the data which comes from server.